# Problemas con el getRol , getEmail

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con angular y springboot.
El problema es : core.mjs:10141 ERROR SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON.

Estoy utilizando un servicio de token para obtener el ROL , EMAIL , TOKEN

Mi objetivo era obtener el rol , email , token del usuario que inicia sesion.
Necesito el rol porque si el rol es USER ,hay cosas que no van a poder ver y tambien lo necesitaba para el nombre y apellido del usuario.
Gracias de antemano y agredezco las recomendaciones

CODIGO:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

const TOKEN_KEY = 'AuthToken';
const EMAIL_KEY = 'AuthEmail';
const ROL_KEY = 'AuthRol';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenServiceService {

  roles : Array<string> =[];

  constructor() { }

  public SetToken(token:string):void{
    window.sessionStorage.removeItem(TOKEN_KEY);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem(TOKEN_KEY,token);
  }

  public getToken():string{
    return sessionStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY)!;
  }

  public setEmail(email:string) :void{
    window.sessionStorage.removeItem(EMAIL_KEY);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem(EMAIL_KEY,email);
  }

  public getEmail():string{
    return sessionStorage.getItem(EMAIL_KEY)!;
  }

  public setRol(rol:string[]):void{

    window.sessionStorage.removeItem(ROL_KEY);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem(ROL_KEY,JSON.stringify(rol));
  }

  public getRol(): string[] {
    this.roles = [];
    if (sessionStorage.getItem(ROL_KEY)) {
      JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(ROL_KEY)!).forEach((authority: any) => {
        this.roles.push(authority.authority);
        console.log("Rol agregado:", authority.authority);
      });
    }
  
    console.log("Roles obtenidos:", this.roles);
    return this.roles;
  }
  
  private decodeToken(token: string): any {
    const payload = token.split('.')[1]; // Extrae la parte del payload del token
    const decodedPayload = atob(payload); // Decodifica la parte base64 del payload
    return JSON.parse(decodedPayload); // Parsea el JSON resultante
  }
  

  


}
```

Comment: ¿Ya te aseguraste de que `getItem(ROL_KEY)` devuelve un valor válido?

Comment: Revise y devuelve un valor indefinido.Estoy revisando el backend viendo como hacer para pasarle el rol , email , token

Comment: en el backend me devuelte esto : {
  "rol": "ADMIN",
  "sub": "admin@gmail.com",
  "iat": 1707604687,
  "exp": 1707691087
} pero no se como aplicarlo en el frontend , me tira este error : login-usuario.component.ts:43 ERROR SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)